# Why did we add an e?

Tags: grammaire, accord, compléments

In this sentence:

> Les eaux de cette rivière sont si pures, ses rivages si enchanteurs
>   qu’on l’a souvent comparée  au Rhin ou au Rhône.

Why did we add an e at the end of *comparée* ? In this case it is a complement objet indirect passe, and the verb does not have to agree unless it is objet direct passe. I am having trouble figuring this out.

Answer (score 3):

The past participle *comparée* agrees with *l'* because *l'* is a direct complement which is placed before. That's the role you're referring to. It's a direct complement since there is no preposition before it. The pronoun *l'* is feminine since it refers to *rivière*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the « COD » (Complement d’objet direct) is before the verb (`a`). So we need to change the adjectives after it. We put comparée because the COD is referring to river, which is a feminine word.

Answer (score 0):

"**l'**", wich refer to the **river** is here the complement d'objet direct of "**comparée**".

If you prefer, you could replace "l'" by "rivière" (I had to teaks verbs tense to pass to live speech):

> Les eaux de cette rivière sont si pures, ses rivages si enchanteurs
>   que **cette rivière** a souvent été comparée au Rhin ou au Rhône.

Comment: "Comparée" is not the complément d'objet direct: "l" is the complement d'objet direct.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wraped it the other way arround

Answer (score 0):

In the past tense when the verb is conjugated with the auxiliary "avoir" the past participle of the verb does not agree neither in genera nor in number with the subject but in particular case it agrees with the direct object complement when this one is placed before the verb. in the case of this sentence the "L" which replaces the direct object complement is placed before the verb "L'a souvent comparé" and seen that "eau" is feminine so we add the "e" to the verb "comparer" .

Comment: No, not *eau(x)* as it would have be *on les a souvent comparées*. The other replies rightly state the agreement is with *rivières*.